# ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: angular

alguien que me ayude, soy nueva en `angular` y no se por que me sale este error al momento de cargar la pagina
`core.mjs:6494 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.`

probe con `window.atob`, igual no funciona e igual con escape pero tampoco funciono, ayuda por favor

login service

```
login(cuenta:Cuenta):Observable<any>{
   const urlEndpoint='http://localhost:8088/oauth/token';

   const credenciales= btoa('clienteLibreria'+':'+'12345');

   const httpheaders=new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form- 
          urlencoded',
          'Authorization':'Basic ' + credenciales});
          let params=new URLSearchParams();
          params.set('grant_type', 'password');
          params.set('username',cuenta.email);
          params.set('password',cuenta.contrasena);

          console.log(params.toString());
          return this.http.post<any>(urlEndpoint,params.toString(), 
               {headers:httpheaders});
}


guardarUsuario(accessToken:string):void{
     let payload=this.obtenerDatosToken(accessToken);
     this._cuenta=new Cuenta();
     this._cuenta.usuario.nombres = payload.nombres;
     this._cuenta.usuario.apellidos = payload.apellidos;
     this._cuenta.email= payload.user_name;
     this._cuenta.rol.nombre=payload.authorities;
              
     sessionStorage.setItem("cuenta",JSON.stringify(this._cuenta));

}

guardarToken(accessToken:string):void{
    this._token=accessToken;
    sessionStorage.setItem('token',accessToken);
 }
```

Al parecer el error es aquí, pero no entiendo como solucionarlo

```
obtenerDatosToken(accessToken:string):any{
  if(accessToken!=null){
    return JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split(".")[1]));
  }
  return null;
}



isAuthenticated():boolean{
   let payload=this.obtenerDatosToken(this.token);
   if(payload !=null && payload.user_name && payload.user_name.length>0 ){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
logout(){
    this._token=null;
    this._cuenta=null;
    sessionStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('cuenta');

 }
```

mas informacion

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZF9jdWVudGE6IjozLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJnYXRlc2NjQGhvdG1haWwuY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIl0sImVtYWlsOiI6ImdhdGVzY2NAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NTg4NDU2NDQsImp0aSI6IjI0Yjk2MjBiLTI3MWUtNGFlOC1hYTZiLTBmZDY2NTBmNjAzMCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudGVMaWJyZXJpYSJ9.ldm-tyelcHevW0ML7b-Os4TY7voHIj3CoUWdSRui60c", "token_type": "bearer", "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZF9jdWVudGE6IjozLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJnYXRlc2NjQGhvdG1haWwuY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIl0sImF0aSI6IjI0Yjk2MjBiLTI3MWUtNGFlOC1hYTZiLTBmZDY2NTBmNjAzMCIsImVtYWlsOiI6ImdhdGVzY2NAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NTg4NDU2NDQsImp0aSI6ImNjOGZkZjQ3LWJlNWYtNGZlNi1iNTFjLWI5ZTcxZTQ1YWY2NCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudGVMaWJyZXJpYSJ9.zdJ7G-NNZI3d_LualRLGHKJxhUP9kBpfkYiFb4KJPVY", "expires_in": 3599, "scope": "read write", "id_cuenta:": 3, "email:": "gatescc@hotmail.com", "jti": "24b9620b-271e-4ae8-aa6b-0fd6650f6030" }
```

Comment: Agrega el contenido del parámetro `accessToken`

Comment: gracias por responder, publique el contenido

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que el parámetro accessToken no tiene los datos que crees, sino el token en un campo y el valor del token ya descodificado. Si usas el string del token, éste se descodifica correctamente:

```js
const accessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZF9jdWVudGE6IjozLCJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJnYXRlc2NjQGhvdG1haWwuY29tIiwic2NvcGUiOlsicmVhZCIsIndyaXRlIl0sImVtYWlsOiI6ImdhdGVzY2NAaG90bWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE2NTg4NDU2NDQsImp0aSI6IjI0Yjk2MjBiLTI3MWUtNGFlOC1hYTZiLTBmZDY2NTBmNjAzMCIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6ImNsaWVudGVMaWJyZXJpYSJ9.ldm-tyelcHevW0ML7b-Os4TY7voHIj3CoUWdSRui60c"


console.log(obtenerDatosToken(accessToken));

function obtenerDatosToken(accessToken){
  if(accessToken!=null){
    return JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split(".")[1]));
  }
  return null;
}
```